# Images showing up that shouldn't in iPad application

Tags: xcode, ios, ipad

I have an iPad application which has many categorized images I need to switch between.

I store the categories in a database, along with the image prefix and number of images for that category.  Using a random number in the range of 0-to-image_count_for_category, I get an image name like this:

[image_prefix][random_number].png => "SomeCategory3.jpg"

The images themselves are included in the project file structure and are not stored in the database.

All the image swapping is going fine.  The problem lies in some of the image usage...  I used to have an image "SomeCategory3.jpg", which was in the application, and has been displayed.  Now, I replace the image named SomeCategory3.jpg, and the old image shows up ... Um ... how is that possible?

I have tried removing the app from the device, cleaning the project, re-building, and re-copying to the device for debug.  Still, the old image comes up in that random rotation.

My app never copy the images anywhere.  I simply reference them using the app folder with the image name appended.

I have verified that the old images are *not* in the folder or referenced by the project.  I have viewed all the images in xcode to ensure the image displays properly.

Yet somehow ... the old image gets used in my random image swapping rotation.

It's driving me mad trying to figure out how the old image is there.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Kevin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode can't tell the image changed and did not overwrite the one in your app bundle's Resources folder. Right-click the image in your Xcode project and click "Touch" then rebuild. That or clean your target and rebuild.

Comment: I couldn't find "touch" in xcode 4 but your second suggestion, to clean and rebuild, worked great! Thank you!

Comment: Right - this answer was pre-Xcode-4. Yeah, sadly the touch command has gone missing in v4. File a bug/enhancement with bugreport.apple.com and tell them touch is still needed.